# File download link with asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Here is the problem I have ran into and I'm not sure of the exact source of the error:

I have inherited a site and I needed to add a resume upload/download feature. The way it works now is a file is uploaded by an applicant and stored on the web server with an entry in the applicant table indicating the file name. A link is created (e.g. ../filedownload.aspx?id=1231) in our backend pointing to my download page that carries the code for downloading the resume. The page finds the entry in the table, creates a path to the file in the folder, then prompts for a save. For some entries it doesn't supply the file specified for download, but rather the download page itself (FileDownload.aspx).

I used a label to see if it was pulling the filename from the table row and it had the right name. It doesn't happen to any certain document type or filename structure. It appears fairly random as far as which entries it happens to.

The site uses LINQ to SQL for accessing the database, which I'm not that familiar with and has weird quirks elsewhere in the site, such as populating text boxes with old values after the entry has been updated.

Has anyone seen or heard of something similar to this?

Comment: The reason that the page `FileDownload.aspx` is specified as the path is most likely because `FileDownload.aspx` is writing to the response stream. This is a perfectly valid way of dynamically grabbing a stream from the database and sending it to the client. Although, a generic handler (.ashx) would be a more suitable and clean solution to write out a file when no page life cycle is needed.

Comment: What would be the reason for this happening on only a few of the applicants?

Comment: Not sure -- it's your code, of which you haven't specified.  I would assume it's most likely around where the link is rendered. Perhaps specific file types do not need be rendered to the response stream when a static location dictates otherwise?

Comment: Alright I think I got it. Thanks for the suggestions.